# how to swap uiTextField with Uilabel easily using xcode editor?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

I have a storyboard with a UITextField.

I want to change it to UILabel and to keep all existing ui constraints.

How can I do this easily? Using the editor. Not programmatically

Comment: *"easily"*? You don't :/ You can try editing the xml but there are some properties a UITextfield has that do not apply to a UILabel which you would have to filter out by hand. There is not builtin way for this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't :( 
If you are doing an iOS 9 app try to use UIStackView Rather than raw constraints...

Comment: when I had textField it had black boundaries. Can I make black boundaries to UILabel too?

Comment: You can do it easily programmatically

Comment: I prefer via the editor as this is is seen to any new developer before run time